# Open symfony/panther in existing browser window

Tags: php, symfony-panther

I'm working on a test script in PHP using Symfony Panther where one of the requirements is to open the website to be tested in a browser window that is already open in the local machine as a new tab (I'm sort of indifferent if the browser is chrome or firefox but I've been using chrome for now).

The default behaviour of `createChromeClient` seem to be to open a completely new chrome window but that undermines my testing effort since I need to load the website within the same browser window as previous tests have been carried out in.

So the question is, is there a way in Panther or underlying libraries to configure the script to open in an existing chrome or firefox window?

My code as a reference point (I'm running the tests in Ubuntu 18.04 gnome by the way):

```
use Symfony\Component\Panther\Client;

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; 

$client = \Symfony\Component\Panther\Client::createChromeClient(null, [
            '--window-size=1200,1100',
            '--disable-gpu',
]);

$client->request('GET', 'https://example.com');
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I think this is a setting in the browser: _"Open links in .... "_. All you can do in HTML is set a target, like "_blank" for a new tab/window, but it is up to the browser to decide which one.

Comment: Good point about the browser settings @kiko software. I've tried to look for "Open links in" in chrome's settings but I couldn't find an option for this. I've even tried to use a chrome plugin for open in tabs but this didn't work either. I also tried to add `'--target-blank'` in createChromeClient but this didn't work either. Any other ideas perhaps?

Comment: Firefox has a setting called: _"Open links in tabs instead of new windows"_, but you're right I cannot find something similar in Chrome. You have to open a link while holding down the Ctrl (win) or ⌘ (mac) key.

Comment: I tried switching to firefox instead of chrome and set the 'open links in tabs instead of windows' to true and then I reran the script with createFirefoxClient. The result is still the same though; the script opens a completely new window.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Panther, which your code uses to open a window. I might insist on a window by setting window capabilities. Setting the window size, for instance, cannot be helpful if you want to open a tab.